# Formatting Dictionary

Tags: python, function, recursion, printing

So I am working  a dictionary with some nice information, and I wan to print out the words in a nicely formatted way by means of another function.

I have this:

```
    norwDict = {
        'et hus': {
            'pron': 'hUs',
            'def': 'house',
            'POS': 'noun',
            'gen': 'neuter', }
        'en blomst' :{
            'pron':'blOMst',
            'def':'flower',
            'POS': 'noun',
            'gen':'masc', }
```

I want to print this so that it looks like:

```
printWord(norwDict, 'blomst')

en blomst (blOmst), noun
    a flower.
```

What things do I do in order to format it like that in the function def printWord()?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `str.format`. See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings

As it is, it would work something like this:

```
def print_word(your_dict, your_word):
    # you need some sort of logic to go from 'blomst' to 'en blomst'
    key, = {k for k in your_dict.keys() if your_word in k}

    # {'pron': 'blOMSt', ... }
    values = your_dict[key]

    print """{key} ({pron}), {POS}
    a {def}""".format(key=key, **values)
```

`str.format` lets you pass in named arguments, which you can easily get here by doing `**` unpacking on your inner `dict`.